# df and where a folder is mounted

Tags: mount, disk-usage

I have  linux system. When I do `df` I get something like

```
Filesystem  1k-blocks  Used  Available  Use%  Mounted on
.... some data here
 /dev/mmcblk0pyy    yyy     yyy    0   100%      /
/dev/mmcblk0pxx     xxxx   xxx    xxxx    98%    /thefolder
```

Now, when I do `ls /` I got a list of some folders among them I have

```
thefolder  thefolder2
```

so I can see that the folder `thefolder` is mounted on  `/dev/mmcblk0pxx`

My question is, where is folder `thefolder2`? Is it in `/dev/mmcblk0pyy`? (since that is `/`)
Does that mean that now `thefolder2` is full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, where is folder thefolder2? Is it in /dev/mmcblk0pyy? (since that is /)

Yes, if it didn't have something explicitly mounted on it, it still belongs to the parent mount. (Just like /etc and /bin are still part of /.)

You can run `df /thefolder2` to have it find the containing mount.

> Does that mean that now thefolder2 is full?

It means that the entire "/" filesystem is full. Since /thefolder2 isn't a separate mount, it does not have its own space accounting; it uses the space of /.

(Meanwhile, "/thefolder" is a separate filesystem with its own space, but is getting close to full as well.)